# highcharts piechart redraw with animation after setData()

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using a piechart from http://www.highcharts.com/

So i am setting the data like this:

```
var cars = [];                            
cars.push({name: "Keine Daten", y: 100});                 

piechart.series[0].setData(cars);
piechart.setTitle({text: 'test '+year+' am '+daytime});
```

But the piechart wont show any animation.

How do i trigger the animation!?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle demo ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with an areaspline chart. Setting the redraw argument in setData to false (`chart.series[0].setData([...], false)`), and then manually calling `chart.redraw()` worked for me. However, I don't think this works well for piecharts.

Answer (score 2):

If you want animation during the set data, you have to update each point separately. In other words, you can use update() function or addPoint()

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update()
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint()

Comment: Does your "during" mean, after i set the data?

Comment: If i am going to do the update Method.. How can i get the current y value of each Point?
for(var i = 1; i <= 23; i++){
      piechart.series[0].data[i].update(NEED POINT HERE);
     }

Answer (score 0):

Just trying out @Sebastian Bochan's answer

```
pie.series[0].addPoint({name: "New Point", y: Math.floor(10 + Math.random() * 30)});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mJRMM/2/

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not solution, because animations is requeired after setData() which is not avaialbe in highcharts.