# Changing baseSeries dynamically for live chart

Tags: highcharts

I am using High Stock chart component to display live signals.It requires addition and deletion of signal at run-time but limited to total 7 signals.I am creating a series for each signal.I get data for signals every second from WebApi in following format

[{"Key":"Signal1","Value":2150,"TimeStamp":"2014-09-29T18:20:23.0008365+05:30"},{"Key":"Signal2","Value":197,"TimeStamp":"2014-09-29T18:20:23.0008365+05:30"},
{"Key":"Signal3","Value":200,"TimeStamp":"2014-09-29T18:20:23.0008365+05:30"}]

### Series

### Index  |   Id/Name

0     -  Signal1
1     -  Signal2
2     -  Signal3

### Navigator

### Index  |  Id/Name

3     -  Navigaotr

By default Navigator always refers to series 0.
But when series 0 is deleted,then Navigator stops working.
I goggled a lot and found 1 solution for this as below.

```
var nav = chart.get('Navigator');
nav.setData(chart.series[1].options.data, true, true, true);
```

But if above procedure is followed Navigator copies only data already present in series 1 and chart as well as Navigator stops animating.But expected behavior is Navigator as well as chart should animate as new points are added to the series 1 every second via ajax call to WebApi.The ajax call to WebApi is as below.

```
function requestData() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: requestUrlString,
    success: function(point) {
        if (point.length > 0 && point.length < 8) {

            if (chart.series.length > 0) {

                var series = chart.series[0],
                    shift = series.options.data.length > 20 * 60 ; // shift if the series is longer than 20

                var dateTime = new Date(point[0].TimeStamp);

                for (i = 0; i < point.length; i++) {

                    if (chart.get(point[i].Key) != null) {
                        chart.get(point[i].Key).addPoint([dateTime.getTime(), point[i].Value], false, shift);
                    }
                }
                chart.redraw();                    
            }

        }
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    },
    cache:false
});
```

}

The method used to change baseSeries is as below.

```
function changeBaseSeries() {    

        chart.series[0].update({
            data: [],
            showInLegend: false
        });
        var nav = chart.get('Navigator');
        nav.setData(chart.series[1].options.data, true, true, true);
        nav.update({ baseSeries: 1 });       
}
```

Could you please provide any input on this ?

I tried chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(); as well in changeBaseSeries() but still Navigator don't animate.

Answer (score 0):

A few clues:

- your data field name needs to by x, and value y.
- dates needs to be timestamps (time in miliseconds)

Comment: While adding point to the series i convert the date to timestamp.

Comment: @Sebastain - I have updated the question with the requestData method which does conversion from date to timestamp.

Comment: Instead of chart.redraw(); betters is using setData();

Comment: @Sebastain - Instead of redrawing chart each time a point is added to series,I use chart.redraw(); to redraw chart once all points are added to corresponding series.

Comment: @Sebastain - I use setData() while changing baseSeries for the Navigator.

Comment: I found one site where you mentioned chart wont animate once setData is called <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921075/highcharts-piechart-redraw-with-animation-after-setdata>

Comment: @Sebastain - Could you please provide code snippet to change baseSeries at runtime to another series and data should be coming from a webApi for that series.

Comment: @Paweł Fus - Could you please provide some code snippet to change baseSeries at runtime to another series and data for that series should come from a webApi.